# How to trigger multiple actions on conditional ng-click

Tags: angularjs

I have the following jsfiddle code: http://jsfiddle.net/838SY/1/

My question is how can I make the following ng-click to set the isEditable only for the clicked entry and at the same time call the edit(object) method?

```
<span ng-click="flag == true||(isEditable=!isEditable)">
```

I've tried this:

```
<span ng-click="flag == true||(isEditable=!isEditable; edit(object))">
```

Doesn't work.

I've tried:

```
<span ng-click="flag == true||edit(object)">
```

and at the edit method level I defined :

```
$scope.isEditable=!$scope.isEditable;
```

this approach will set the isEditable value for all the list elements, which is not what I want. I only want it set for the clicked element.

Any ideas?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this sintax:
`flag == true? edit(object):false`

Comment: And how do I control the value of isEditable if I'm using this syntax?    I'm hitting the same problem with this approach.

Comment: Thank but i believe you misunderstood my question. My initial example is doing exactly this.

Comment: What i need is something like this:

Comment: <span ng-click="flag == true?isEditable=!isEditable;edit(object):false">&nbsp;{{flag}}-{{object.text}}</span>

Comment: This will not be accepted by angular but I hope you can understand what i want to do

Comment: So basically both isEditable=!isEditable and edit(object) should be called when the condition is satisfied.

Comment: @gelu gara Just remove  `isEditable=!isEditable` to the `edit` function. Like this: http://jsfiddle.net/Dn8Fh/1/

Comment: I've mentioned this scenario in my question description. By doing that : $scope.isEditable=!$scope.isEditable; the isEditable value will be set for all the list elements. I only what the text field to be visible for the element that was clicked not for the whole list.

Answer (score 0):

```
    <div ng-show="!isEditable">
       <input type="text" ng-model="object.text" ng-blur="isEditable!=isEditable;update(object);edit(object);" />
    </div>
```

This will call the multiple methods when the user get blurred from the text box.So, by this you can specify the multiple methods that need to be called on the blur event of the text box

Comment: My problem is with the  <span ng-click="flag == true||(isEditable=!isEditable)">&nbsp;{{flag}}-{{object.text}}</span> not with the input tag.